# SQL query to get row count

Tags: php, sql

I have a query in my PHP where I'm searching for string:

```
select * from feed1 where PNAME like '%clothes%' limit 5;
```

I also want to get count of PNAME like cloth for which I'm using separate search query:

```
$qry=mysqli_query(select * from feed1 where PNAME like '%clothes%');
$rows=mysqli_num_rows($qry);
```

Rows query is taking too much time to load the page. Is there any way we can get total row count and limit of up to 5 products from one query? Thereby, the load time will decrease.

```
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+------
-------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardi
nality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+------
-------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| xml   |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | BOSID       | A         |
  7233 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+------
-------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: run `show indexes from feed1` this will tell you more why its slow.

Comment: i ran the above query sir.but dont know how to check the parameters.can u please guide

Comment: YOu need to run this on mysql directly and it will show you the indexes for the table.

Comment: i ran it and got some data as well but not able to understand that

Comment: copy that in the question.

Comment: copied sir.please check@AbhikChakraborty

Comment: Ok you do have any index on this table and using where clause on a non index field makes it extreme slow. Try running this to your mysql 1. `alter table feed1 add index pname_idx (PNAME);` then execute the query and see what happens.

Comment: now i m out of memory allocated when running and sir.my cardinality for BOSID  is 207561 now

Comment: hmm how many records to you have in that table and what is the datatype of the field PNAME ?

Comment: now around 2lakh.datatype is varchar

Comment: humm, varchar is good. But adding an index definitely makes it better. Take a backup of the table first. Then check in the table if the index is added properly. using the same command `show indexes from feed1` you can see the index name in the list. The query optimizer will look for index when you have where clause and if no index then will scan the entire table.

Comment: actually for this new index ,cardinality is coming as 1.is that an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this by one query, but for get count, use `COUNT(*)` instead of get all the data out.

To get the count:

```
select count(*) from feed1 where PNAME like '%clothes%'
```

then get first 5:

```
select * from feed1 where PNAME like '%clothes%' limit 5
```

There should be at least two queries for pagination.

Comment: using first query for count will take less time is it sir?

Comment: @user3564442 At least will take less time than get all data out, and you may check your database indexes.

Comment: still it took4-5 seconds.how to check for indexes sir